# To understand a line of jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, button

What does the following line mean?

```
jQuery.post('/codes/handlers/delete_a_question.php', 
{ question_id: jQuery(this).attr('question_id') }
```

Context in HEAD,

```
jQuery('a.delete_question').live('click', function(){
    jQuery.post('/codes/handlers/delete_a_question.php', 
    { question_id: jQuery(this).attr('question_id') }, 
        function(data){
            alert ("Output of the delete.php -page: " + data );
                                        // `data` is probably unnecessary
    }) 
});
```

My handler in `/codes/delete_a_question.php`,

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=noa user=noa password=123");
$result = pg_prepare ( $dbconn, "delete_question_query",
    "DELETE FROM questions
    WHERE question_id = $1"
);
$result = pg_execute ( $dbconn, "delete_question_query", array ( $_GET['question_id'] ) );
header( "Location: /codes/index.php?successful_removal");
```

HTML,

```
 echo ("<a href='#' class='delete_question'"
      . " id=question_id'" . $question_id . "'"   // to have question_id777
      . ">delete</a>"
 );
```

I am trying to remove a question if the user clicks a link first by getting the question_id from GET. However, I have not managed to get the jQuery code to work. I get the following popup and the question is not removed.

I get now as a popup [this code](http://dpaste.com/83881/) after solving the problem with one `(` and changing `$_GET` to `$_POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you translate it to plain English this code:

```
jQuery.post('/codes/handlers/delete_a_question.php', 
{ question_id: jQuery(this).attr('question_id') }
```

reads:

> "Asynchronously make a POST request to '/codes/handlers/delete_a_question.php' with the parameter 'question_id' who's value should be the value of 'question_id' html attribute of 'this'."

In your case 'this' would refer to the link being clicked on to delete a question. It's looking for an attribute named 'question_id' which is not a valid HTML attribute (or XHTML) attribute for an anchor tag. This may be causing the problem.

Where in the link tag are you storing the question id? If you are using XHTML you could use the "rel" attribute, who's job it is to define the relationship between an anchor and what it links to (in this case it could be the relationship between the link and the question to be deleted).

So change this:

```
<a href="#" class="delete_question" question_id="123">delete</a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="#" class="delete_question" rel="123">delete</a>
```

and then in your javascript/jQuery change this:

```
{ question_id: jQuery(this).attr('question_id') }
```

to this:

```
{ question_id: jQuery(this).attr('rel') }
```

Answer (score 1):

[post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

> Load a remote page using an HTTP POST
>   request.

In this case **loads delete_a_question.php**

[attr](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr)

The second parameter is key/value pairs or the return value of the .serialize() function that will be sent to the server.

In this case the attribute **question_id** of the clicked anchor is taken

function(data)

is the **callback function** to be executed when the data is loaded successfully.

[live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

binds a handler to an event for the matched element.

In this case **binds a click event handler**.

Comment: **What should I put to the data?** Question_id? It seems to be unnecessary for me.

Comment: Only the first parameter for the post function is mandatory. So if you don't need the question id parameter then remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The method signature for [$.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) is:

```
jQuery.post( url, [data], [callback], [type] )
```

So in this line:

```
jQuery.post('/codes/handlers/delete_a_question.php', 
{ question_id: jQuery(this).attr('question_id') }
```

the first string parameter is the URL the post request will be sent to, and the second is an object containing data as key/value pairs. The third (which in the case of your code appears on the next line) is a callback function. The only mandatory parameter is the first one.

JQuery's $.post method encapsultes an [$.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) call with the type option set to "POST".

Answer (score 1):

Your solution doesn't exactly relate to your question, but you're missing a `)` on the `pg_execute` line in your PHP and that's what the error's about.

Comment: **Thank you for pointing that out!** The same problem persists still.  I get now as a popup the source code of my `index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the problem is in the PHP code and not the jQuery -

The problem you are having is likely related to the fact that you are getting the parameter "question_id" using the $_GET method:

```
$_GET['question_id']
```

which only retrieves parameters from a GET request. In this case you are making a POST request (with the jQuery.post() function), so you should use

```
$_POST['question_id']
```

instead.